# How to set margin of titletoc

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

I am currently doing my thesis. I am going to create a table of content.
I use titlesec and itletoc to manage my TOC.

However, some chapter heading is perfect alignment but some chapter is not.

Therefore, I would like to know.
How can I set the margin of the title chapter in a table of content?

This is the result of my content.

[image]

In the above figure, I would like to set the margin of the title name not over the green line. The green line is set at the center of the page or third quartile of the page. Therefore, the title is not allowed over the green line margin.

This is my sample code.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Layout packages
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=20mm]{geometry}

%%% toc packages                                                                                                      
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lineno}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \chapter*{Contents}%
    \begin{flushright}
        \textbf{page}
    \end{flushright}
    % Hold current page value
    % for TOC heading
    \newcounter{tocitem}
    \setcounter{tocitem}{0}
    \modulolinenumbers[50]
    \linenumbers[1]
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \setcounter{tocitem}{0}
    \clearpage
    \cleardoublepage
}
\makeatother

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0mm]
{\stepcounter{tocitem}}
{\MakeUppercase\chaptername\hspace{1ex}\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[0.6pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{section}
[0mm]
{\stepcounter{tocitem}}
{\hspace{\firstindentlength}\thecontentslabel.\hspace{2mm}}
{\hspace{\firstindentlength}\thecontentslabel\hspace{2mm}}
{\titlerule*[0.6pc]{.}\contentspage} 


\begin{document}
    
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter{new chapter1}
\newpage
\chapter{This is a handbook about TeX, a new typesetting system intended for the creation of beautiful books and especially for books that contain a lot of mathematics.}
\newpage
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post a small *complete* code that we can test? Help us to help!

Comment: Thank you, I have been edited my post and give a small complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've well understood, you can do that with `\contentsmargin`.

I took the liberty to add some vertical padding between chapters in the table of contents, which will make it easier to read. I also removed the `\newpage` after each chapter: it's unnecessary, since the book class starts each chapter on a nawpage by default.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Layout packages
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=20mm]{geometry}

%%% toc packages
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lineno}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \chapter*{Contents}%
    \begin{flushright}
        \textbf{page}
    \end{flushright}
    % Hold current page value
    % for TOC heading
    \newcounter{tocitem}
    \setcounter{tocitem}{0}
    \modulolinenumbers[50]
    \linenumbers[1]
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \setcounter{tocitem}{0}
    \clearpage
    \cleardoublepage
}
\makeatother
\contentsmargin{0.3\textwidth}
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0mm]
{\stepcounter{tocitem}}
{\MakeUppercase\chaptername\hspace{1ex}\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[0.6pc]{.}\contentspage}[\vskip 1.5ex]

\titlecontents{section}
[0mm]
{\stepcounter{tocitem}}
{\hspace{\firstindentlength}\thecontentslabel.\hspace{2mm}}
{\hspace{\firstindentlength}\thecontentslabel\hspace{2mm}}
{\titlerule*[0.6pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{new chapter1}
\chapter{This is a handbook about TeX, a new typesetting system intended for the creation of beautiful books and especially for books that contain a lot of mathematics.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it easy to solve that? I have spent my time to find a solution. Thank you so much.